# Find the total number of positive integral solutions for $x,y,z$ such that $xyz=24$

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations

I recognize that this is related to the stars and bars algorithm, but I am just not able to apply it here

The general method is factor the number, in this case is $2^3\times 3$, but what next?

It’s explained using some weird and hopelessly arbitrary box analogy, which all goes over my head.

How is this question solved?

Comment: $x$, $y$ and $z$ are three boxes, into which you need to place three $2$'s and a $3$. Is this the analogy you're talking about?

Comment: @Arthur yes. How is it possible to fit a 3 in the boxes if each box only allows one element?

Comment: Who said the boxes only allow one element each?

Comment: @Arthur exactly. I have no idea what’s going on

Comment: The numbers here are small enough that you should be able to solve this problem by simply *listing* all the possibilities. Why not just do that?

Comment: @BarryCipra I don’t want to do it that way. I want to know the right method (Although I did solve it by individually listing them out; still a lengthy process)

Comment: The point here is that putting a 2 and a 3 in the $x$-box corresponds to setting $x=2\cdot3=6$. Putting two 2's in the $y$-box corresponds to setting $y=2\cdot2=4$. And then there are no more numbers to put in the $z$-box, so we get $z=1$. Together, this makes one possible solution to $xyz=24$, namely $6\cdot4\cdot1=24$. Does this make sense to you?

Comment: @Arthur yes, but I don’t know how it relates to $\binom{n+r-1}{r-1}$

Comment: Hello is my answer helpful

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Imagine you have $3$ boxes. You may place a $2,2,2,3$ among the boxes, and when you multiply all the boxes together, you get $24$. First, spread the $2$s. There are $3$ of these twos, and $3$ boxes, so that means you need $2$ dividers.

It should look like this o|o|o, where | is divider, and o represents a $2$. You can place $2$ dividers among the $5$ spots.

Thus, the possible ways to spread the $2$s are equal to $ 5 \choose 2$ or $10$ ways. Now, find the number of ways to spread the $3$. The $3$ can go in any of the $3$ boxes, so $3$ ways. Now you have $3*10$ or $30$ possible ways.

NOTE: A box without any numbers will just have a value of $1$, adding numbers into the box multiplies the numbers in the box together.

You can also find all the combinations easily by listing out each triplet from least to greatest, then rearranging to find the rest.

The combinations are:

$(1,1,24): 3$ ways

$(1,2,12)$ : $6$ ways

$(1,3,8)$ : $6$ ways

$(1,4,6)$ : $6$ ways

$(2,2,6)$ : $3$ ways

$(2,3,4)$ : $6$ ways

This also gives us $30$ ways total

Comment: In that case, shouldn’t 1 also be accounted for?

Comment: Also which spots are you referring to?

Comment: The places with the o and |