# The total number of positive integral solutions $(x,y,z)$ such that $xyz=24$

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations

I tried it this way,
Since $x,y,z$ are three different variables,
$$xyz=24=2^3×3$$
So each of the $2s$ and the $3$ has three variables(either x,y or z) it can go to.
Therefore number of positive solutions $=3×3×3×3=81$ which is much greater than the actual answer (given 30).
**So why am I wrong?**

[image: Question]

Comment: If the first two goes to $x$ and the second to $y,$ this gives the same values as when the first $2$ goes to $y$ and the second to $y.$ So you have overcounted those examples.

Comment: Does rearranging the variables (e.g., $(1, 2, 12)$ vs. $(2, 1, 12)$) count as a distinct solution?

Comment: @GeoffreyTrang It is not specified in the attached question image but it should right, since x,y,z are 3 different variables

Comment: I see the use of tuples to represent the solutions. Does that mean that the solutions are ordered, i.e. (3, 1, 8) is different from (3, 8, 1)?

Comment: For $xyz=8$ there are $10$ solutions: $(x,y,z)=(2,2,2),(4,2,1),(2,4,1),(2,1,4),(4,1,2),(1,4,2),(1,2,4),(8,1,1),(1,8,1)$ or $(1,1,8)$.  For each of those, to get $xyz=24$, multiply one of the variables by $3$, yielding $3\times10=30$ solutions

Comment: Asked [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4049001/find-the-total-number-of-positive-integral-solutions-for-x-y-z-such-that-xyz)

Comment: @J.W.Tanner So the order of variables matters but then why is my answer wrong ?

Comment: @Aurelius:  see Thomas Andrews' comment above

Comment: @ThomasAndrews So what you're saying is that by my method, each two is treated as a unique 2?

Comment: Imagine the three $2$s were three different colors.  Red, green and yellow.  You are counting putting the red $2$ in $x$ and the green $2$ in $y$ as a different result from putt the the green $2$ in $x$ and the red $2$ in $y$.  But twos are twos so it doesn't matter whether the $2$ in the $x$ is the red one or the green one.  So you are way overcounting.

Comment: Perhaps a similar way to do it would be that there are $3$ places to put the $3$ in.  Now you are left with figuring out how pour the three $2$s into three containers.  (Stars and Bars.  Or brute force.  Or horse sense.  Count the ways to put all three in one container.  Then the ways to put two in one container and one in a second container. And finally the ways to put them all in different containers.)

Comment: @fleablood By Stars and Bars, There are 7 spaces $—,—,—,—,—,—,—$ and 7 characters  $2,2,2,3,x,y,z$? And anything on the left of a box(x,y,z) is included in that variable. (Idk if I should ask this as a separate question or if it's better in the comments)

Comment: @Aurelius Well, that wasnt the point I was making - I was talking about the way your approach overcounts certain examples. But your formulation is another way of thinking about the error.

Comment: I was thinking of just where to put the $2$s seperately from the issue of where to put the single $3$.  There are $3$ choices for where to but the three.  The issue is how to place the two $2$ into three spots.  Pretty sure stars and bars  gives the right answer.  ${5\choose 3}=10$.  And then the three places for the $3$s gives us $3\times 10$.  But I did brute force. $3$ ways to put all three $2$s in the same slot plus $3\times 2$ ways to put two $2$s in one slot and one $2$ in another, plus $1$ way to put all the $2$s in different slots.  That adds to $10$.

Comment: Even brute force:  $(24,1,1)=[3] . (12,2,1)=[6].(8,4,1)=[6].(8,2,2)=[3].(6,4,1)=[6], (6,2,2)=[3].(4,3,2)=[6]$ (working with $x \ge y \ge z$ and just doing all possibilities from highest numbers first.  The numbers in the square brackets are the numbers of ways to arrange the them) so $3+6+6+6+3+6=30$-- even that wouldn't take to long to do on a test.... well, maybe it would.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are wrong because of **double counting** (a common mistake in combinatorics).

Lets label the three $2$s as $2_1$, $2_2$, and $2_3$. Here are a few of the possibilities you are counting.

$$\begin{array}{c|c|c} 
 \text{ A } & \text{ B } & \text{ C }\\ \hline
2_1 & 2_2 \times 2_3 & 3 \\ \hline
2_2 & 2_1 \times 2_3 & 3 \\ \hline
2_3 & 2_1 \times 2_2 & 3
\end{array}$$

Now, you are counting these as three distinct solutions, when they are one and the same solution $(2, 4, 3)$.

---

Here's how you can approach this problem intuitively.

There are three $2$s we need to distribute among A, B, and C. [We are free to assign anything from zero to all the $2$s to a variable.]

To do that, imagine there are $5$ positions [$3$ for the $2$s and then (for the variables), $3 - 1 = 2$ will remain vacant acting as separators].

[$2$s to the left of the first vacant position will go to A, those between the two vacancies will go to B, and the third group to C.$^*$ ]

Now, we can place three $2$s in $5$ positions in $\binom{5}{3} = 10$ ways. Same as choosing $3$ positions out of $5$.$^{**}$

Finally, the single $3$ we have can be assigned to the three variables in $\binom{3}{1}$ ways.

So, altogether we have $10×3=30$ ways and each represents a unique solution.

---

$^*$ A couple of examples. $\times$ represent empty positions.

$$ 2 \, \times \, 2 \,\, 2 \,\, \times$$

This (above) represents A getting one $2$, B two $2$s, and C none.

And the following represents A getting one $2$, B getting none, and C two $2$s.

$$ 2 \,\, \times \, \times \,\, 2 \,\, 2 $$

$^{**}$ Generally, if we have $n$ variables adding together to give a sum of $S$ and individual variables can be zero, the number of possible solutions would be given by $\binom{S + n - 1}{S}$. Or $\binom{S+n-1}{n-1}$, same value but often easier to calculate.

In our case here, the sum of $3$ variables had to be $3$. So $n = 2$ and $S = 3$.

Comment: There are three $2$s so there should be four positions for the sticks, right? So it should become $^{4}C_2$

Comment: @Aurelius Thanks for pointing it out. Made the correction.

Comment: Can I do it: 6 spaces:$—,—,—,—,—,—$ and two separators are to be placed followed by selecting a space for 3 (out of remaining 4). The 2s can occupy the rest . So $$\cfrac{6!}{4!.2!} \times \cfrac{4!}{3!}$$ This seems right but gives 60

Comment: I don't get it. what exactly are you doing here? what are those 6 spaces for?

Comment: For placing 4 numbers and 2 separators $2,2,2,3,|,|$  Example $22|2|3$

Comment: Oh no, it doesn't work that way. The things being distributed have to be identical. So if we are distributing $2$s, it's okay. But we can't mix $3$ with it. That's why in the solution, I took care of $3$ separately.

Answer (score 5):

We want $x,y,z\in \Bbb N$ such that
$$xyz = 24 = 2^3 \times 3^1.$$
By the fundamental theorem of arithmetic, the variables $x,y,z$ are of the form
$$x = 2^{a_1} 3^{b_1},\\y = 2^{a_2} 3^{b_2},\\z = 2^{a_3} 3^{b_3}.$$
Thus, finding $x,y,z$ amounts to solving the systems $$a_1 + a_2 + a_3 = 3 \text{ and } b_1 + b_2 + b_3 = 1,$$
for $a_i,b_i\ge 0$. The [number of non-negative integer solutions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/919676/the-number-of-integer-solutions-of-equations) of the first equation is $$\binom{3+3-1}{3-1} = \binom{5}{2},$$
and that of the second is
$$\binom{1+3-1}{3-1} = \binom{3}{2}.$$
The total number is
$$\binom{5}{2} \cdot \binom{3}{2} = 10 \cdot 3 = 30.$$

Comment: Can I also use the stars and bars method? There are 7 spaces $—,—,—,—,—,—,—$ and 7 characters to be arranged : $$2,2,2,3,x,y,z$$

Comment: You only want to use stars and bars if you have all of the same things and put them into specific containers.  The $3$ is different from the $2$s.  And the $x,y,z$ are containers, not items.  The "bars" are  breaks *between* containers.  So to place the $2$s you have three stars (the twos) and you have two bars (between the $x|y$ and the $y|z$).  And for the $3$ you have one star (the three) and two bars (the same).  So by stars and bars it is ${3\choose 1}\times {5\choose 3}$.